# UI | Red Dot Meaning

Tags: support

I'm not sure if this is the right spot for this question, but today I noticed that I had a red dot in my Review Tasks --- I don't know what this means. Can anyone give some insights???

[image]

Now this morning it shows it like this---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that there are items in your cue to review.  In the example shown, there are late answers for you to review and provide feedback on.  Click, and the questions/answers will appear, along with action items, so that you can contribute to maintaining the site.